# How to check if a argv argument is a number and nothing else with sscanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I have to use sscanf or scanf.

```
if (sscanf(argv[x],"%d", &numb) == 1) {
       do smt 
  };
```

My Problem is the case when the argument is something like 10xyz. In this case, I always got a EOF and the program stops immediately. But i dont want the program to stop what so ever.

xyz10 or 10xyz or 10x10 should not be a number of course, but i dont want my program stop because of this arguments. So how do i check if the argument is a number with sscanf without any EOF while the argument could be any combination of any characters ?

Comment: Why not simply do character processing instead of `sscanf`? `char *cp=argv[1]; while (isidigit(*cp)) cp++; if (*cp) /*not a number*/`

Comment: Because i have to use sscanf :( its not optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop trough the arguments and qualify if each argument is a integer by doing this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num,dummy;
    for (int i=argc-1;i;i--){
        if (sscanf(argv[i], "%d%c", &num, &dummy) == 1) {
            printf("Got a integer -> %d\n",num);
        } else {
         printf("Got garble\n");
        }
    }
 return 0;
}
```

A input like this ->
10 20 10dje 60

Produces a output like this ->

Got a integer -> 60

Got garble

Got a integer -> 20

Got a integer -> 10

Comment: This is the thing i did, but the case that dont work is 10dje. number than string but without whitespace. This is the only case i had problems with. So how to check the case 20xyz ?

Comment: Ok.. will edit my answer... Did not understand your question 100%

Comment: Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: In the exact moment i fixed it myself doing what you just wrote. I was trying to do %d%s but didnt work. When i used %d%c it worked. Thank you very much anyway :D

Comment: Thanks... mark as a valid answer for others who search stack.. l8r.